# Flink Fails on kafka NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have flink 1.14.4 job that have 2 kafka sources and 2 kafka sinks.
After a time my job failed on the error

```java
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/security/scram/internals/ScramSaslClient$1
```

The error cause a crash loop that flink restart won't fix.

The only thing that seems to help is redeploy the flink environment and rerun the job.
The environment run on a kubernetes cluster and deployed by helm and argoccd

Comment: If it "sometimes" works, then you have a missing dependency on the classpath of a subset of servers running the code, or it has been manually added to others.

Comment: most probably an environment variable set manually before.

Comment: Should all the dependencies be on the classpath? How can it be that at start of the run the jobs run and after some restart it fails? What environment variable can cause this problem?